# Selenium selecting from Dropdown Python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I'm using selenium in python and I'm looking to select the option Male from the below:

```
<div class="formelementcontent">
          <select aria-disabled="false" class="Width150" id="ctl00_Gender" name="ctl00$Gender" onchange="javascript: return doSearch();" style="display: none;">
           <option selected="selected" title="" value="">
           </option>
           <option title="Male" value="MALE">
            Male
           </option>
           <option title="Female" value="FEM">
            Female
           </option>
          </select>
```

Before selecting from the dropdown, I need to switch to iframe

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

I've tried many options and searched extensively. This gets me most of the way.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_Gender-button").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_Gender")))
select=Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_Gender"))
check=select.select_by_visible_text('Male')
```

If I use WebDriverWait it times out.

I've tried selecting by visible text and index, both give:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Element  could not be scrolled into view

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared the `<select>` tag is having the value of *style* attribute set as **`display: none;`**. So using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) it would be tough interacting with this [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139).

If you access the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the webpage through [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools), presumably you will find a couple of `<li>` nodes equivalent to the `<option>` nodes within an `<ul>` node. You may be required to interact with those.

You can find find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [select kendo dropdown using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767150/select-kendo-dropdown-using-selenium-python/58767346#58767346)
- [How to test non-standard drop down lists through a crawler using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224924/how-to-test-non-standard-drop-down-lists-through-a-crawler-using-selenium-and-py/44235532#44235532)
- [How to select an option from a dropdown of non select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399713/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-of-non-select-tag/57402060#57402060)

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Gender'))
select.select_by_value('MALE')
```

**Note** add below imports to your solution :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

**Solution 2:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_Gender']/option[text()='Male']").click()
```

Comment: Tried that and still getting the error, Element could not be scrolled into view. Also edited original post to add that I switch to iframe before selecting

Comment: use Action class/ javascript to move on to element and then select a value from drop-down