# UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <li>error selecting li element from a Dropdown using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I wish to click on New Test. The HTML code looks something like this.
I'm new here and beginning to learn automation using selenium-python.

```
<li id="testing">

<ul class="dd">
    <li><a href="javascript:toolsPopup('/abc/xyz/text.html');"><span>New Test</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:toolsPopup('/abc/xyz/list.html');"><span>Test List</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The code that I'm trying to use

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id('testing')
drp=Select(element)
drp.select_by_visible_text('New Test')
```

But getting the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <li>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As dropdown element with text as **New Test** is not with in a `Select` node you can't use `Select` class. To select `<option>` with text  as **New Test** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li#testing > ul.dd li > a[href*='/abc/xyz/text.html'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='testing']/ul[@class='dd']//li/a/span[text()='New Test']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to test non-standard drop down lists through a crawler using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224924/how-to-test-non-standard-drop-down-lists-through-a-crawler-using-selenium-and-py/44235532#44235532)
- [select kendo dropdown using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767150/select-kendo-dropdown-using-selenium-python/58767346#58767346)

Answer (score 0):

The Select method works only for dropdowns which has HTML tag select.
In your case you can not use a select method, just write locator( XPath, CSS, or else) for the element which you want to detect from the dropdown.

In your case the XPath of the element which you wanted should be:

```
//li[text()='New Test']
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Norayr, however if I try

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a').click()`

I'm getting the error : 
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Yes, this is another issue not related to the first problem, now you should wait for the element to be clickable and then perform the click.
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.xpath, "your_xpath")).click()

Comment: I already have a time.sleep(10) before performing the click() verb.still getting the error. Not sure why

Comment: Try with actions or with JSExecutor