# Select DropDown value using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a dropdown value using Selenium in Python but not able to do so. The code I get from "Copy Selector" is this.

```
#mui-12848
```

The complete HTML is

```
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input Reports-autocompleteInput-133 MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="Monthly" id="mui-12848" aria-activedescendant="mui-12848-option-1" aria-controls="mui-12848-popup">
```

I have tried

```
s1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("mui-12848"))
s1.select_by_visible_text('Quarterly')
```

which gives the following error
**UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on  elements, not on**

I have also tried

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[@id='mui-12848'][2]")).click();
```

which gives the following error
**TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

Any help is appreciated.

Following is the Screenshot
[image: The Screenshot of the DropDown Component]

Comment: Your element is not a `SELECT` but an `INPUT`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619301/unexpectedtagnameexception-message-select-only-works-on-select-elements-not

Comment: @Mayank You need to provide the `html` of the list! the input you are showing is not the desired element! You can provide the URL or the `html` and then we can help.

Comment: @MosheSlavin I have pasted the html in the question... Do you mean there is any other HTML I need to provide?

Comment: @Mayank Yes, the list should be in a different element

Answer (score 0):

Try using `expected_conditions`. See below. Replace `browser =  .....` with your code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = .....

# ADD YOUR CODE TO GET TO THE PAGE WITH THE BUTTON

to_click = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mui-12848'][2]")))

to_click.click()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried your approach but I got the error "TimeoutException: Message: "

Comment: I have added the screenshot if it is of any help

Comment: @Mayank I updated the answer to use `presence_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable`.  If that does not work then the xpath needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` type for that HTML element is `text`, it's not a `Select` or a dropdown. The selenium class supports `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on elements, not on
```

...implies that you tried to use `Select()` class which works only on `<select>` element where as the desired element was an `<input>` element.

To click on the `<input>` element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class*='MuiInputBase-input'][id^='mui'][value='Monthly']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'MuiInputBase-input') and starts-with(@id, 'mui')][@value='Monthly']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class*='MuiInputBase-input'][id^='mui'][value='Monthly']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class, 'MuiInputBase-input') and starts-with(@id, 'mui')][@value='Monthly']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried both of your approaches of "CSS_Selector" and "XPATH". In both of them, I got this error "TimeoutException: Message: "

Comment: I have added the screenshot if it is of any help

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect.
It should be like `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mui-12848']").click()`

Moreover, you cannot include the index inside the locator. You will need to use `find_elements` first and then use the index on top of that: `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mui-12848']")[2].click()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried your approach but I got this error "InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ////*[@id='mui-12848'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '////*[@id='mui-12848']' is not a valid XPath expression."

Comment: I have added the screenshot if it is of any help

Comment: There should be only two backslash `//`. I have made that change in my answer. Also, `id` in your screenshot is different than the one I used in my code snippet, so make sure to update that as well.

Comment: Also, since it's  `input` type, try directly with: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mui-23895']").send_keys("Yearly")`