# UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <ul> error selecting an Dropdown option using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dropdown, webdriverwait

The objective is to select either one of the four sub menus (i.e., `Subject area, Title, Publisher, ISSN`) as depicted in the picture below from the Scopus website that accessible via the link: https://www.scopus.com/sources?zone=TopNavBar&origin=NO%20ORIGIN%20DEFINED

[image]

The html snippet for the `search result comb drop menu` by the class name  `ui-menu ui-corner-bottom ui-widget ui-widget-content` is

```html
<ul aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="srcResultComboDrp-button" id="srcResultComboDrp-menu" role="listbox" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-corner-bottom ui-widget ui-widget-content" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-1" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 251px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper ui-state-active">Subject area</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Title</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Publisher</div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <div id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">ISSN</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Say we are interested to select the sub-menu `Title`, then the objective can be achieved as suggested by [OP1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7972225/6446053), by the following lines;

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:Browsers\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'https://www.scopus.com/sources?zone=TopNavBar&origin=NO%20ORIGIN%20DEFINED'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-id-2"]').click()
```

However, the compiler return the following error;

> Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ui-id-2"]"}

Similarly, using the following line as suggested by [OP2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613320/6446053)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:Browsers\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'https://www.scopus.com/sources?zone=TopNavBar&origin=NO%20ORIGIN%20DEFINED'
driver.get(url)
my_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('srcResultComboDrp-menu'))
my_select.select_by_visible_text('Title')
```

Return the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <ul>
```

May I know where did I do wrong? Appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select either of the four sub menus among *Subject area*, *Title*, *Publisher* and *ISSN* as the items are within child `<div>` tags of their  parent `<li>` tag, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Selecting **Title** using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.scopus.com/sources?zone=TopNavBar&origin=NO%20ORIGIN%20DEFINED")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-selectmenu-text' and text()='Subject area']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='srcResultComboDrp-menu']//li[@class='ui-menu-item']/div[text()='Title']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to test non-standard drop down lists through a crawler using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224924/how-to-test-non-standard-drop-down-lists-through-a-crawler-using-selenium-and-py/44235532#44235532)
- [select kendo dropdown using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767150/select-kendo-dropdown-using-selenium-python/58767346#58767346)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Debanjan, it work like a charm. However,I wonder how you get the two `XPATH`. I am unable to locate same `XPATH`  as per your suggestion, using copy `XPATH`  in dev mode on both `Google Chrome` and `Firefox`

Comment: @balandongiv The initial element is a `<span>` and on clicking the `<li>` tag gets displayed. I was able to get it through dev tools with _Chrome 83.0_

Comment: In my `Chrome 83.0.4103.116`, selecting the `XPATH` of the `<span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Subject area</span>` give me '//*[@id="srcResultComboDrp-button"]/span[2]'. But,despite the different in `XPATH` name, the overall framework still work flawlessly. Appreciate it.