# UnexpectedTagNameException: Select only works on <select> elements, not on "<form>" error selecting a drop-down value using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to select an option from this dropdown with Selenium using Python

```html
<div class="form-group mt-2 mb-3 p-3">
                            <form id="did_atd_provide_pnc">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <label for="did_atd_provide_pnc">Did ATD Consultants provide a Plan & Cost review for
                                        this project*?</label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm required-field atd_provided_dropdown" id="did_atd_provide_pnc"
                                            name="did_atd_provide_pnc" data-error-name="Did ATD Provide P&C">
                                        <option value="">-----</option>
                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

I am writing this code

```html
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('did_atd_provide_pnc'))
select.select_by_visible_text('No')
```

But I am getting this error

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Select only works on <select> elements, not on "<form>"
```

Is there any other solution I can test this case with any other reliable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough. However the first element to be identified through `find_element_by_id('did_atd_provide_pnc')` is the `<form>` tag, where as your desired element is the `<select>` tag.

Hence, the `Select()` throws error with the `<form>` element as:

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Select only works on <select> elements, not on "<form>"
```

---

### Solution

To select `<option>` with text as **No** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `select_by_visible_text()`:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='did_atd_provide_pnc' and @name='did_atd_provide_pnc']")))).select_by_visible_text("No")
  ```
- Using *xpath* `select_by_value()`:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='did_atd_provide_pnc' and @name='did_atd_provide_pnc']")))).select_by_value("No")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on  elements, not on  error selecting an Dropdown option using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827123/unexpectedtagnameexception-message-select-only-works-on-select-elements-not/62827315#62827315)